# How to move files between subfolders with same name with bash?

Tags: bash

I want to write a bash script to move every file in one subfolder into another subfolder of the same name in a different folder. I tried the following script, which I called merge.bash:

```
file_path=/home/path/folder
mv subfolder/* "$file_path"/subfolder
```

When I ran this with:

```
bash merge.bash
```

It returned the error:

```
mv: target '/home/path/subfolder'$'\r' is not a directory
```

Why has it added '$'\r   ?

Comment: It is a windows line endings, aka carriage return. The code was written in a windows file/text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Using notepad++ for example, and look at the end of each line, there is a setting to change to Windows CRLF, which stands for Carriage Return Line Feed, for Linux it is LF, which stands for Line Feed, and for Mac it is CR, which stands for Carriage Return.

Comment: The code was written in notepad. I removed the carriage return with sed -i 's/\r//g' merge.bash and it works now. Thanks a lot!